# how to add alt tag in ipslot in impresspages

Tags: image, alt, impresspages

I want to add alt tag in this,but when I use this, It doesnot work.

'244','height' => '163','id' => 'image1','default' => ipThemeUrl('assets/img/ani.png'), 'class' => 'img-responsive'); echo ipSlot('image', $options); ?>

Comment: Missing some part of the code. And style it as a code (adding 4 spaces in front of each line).

Comment: <?php $options = array( 
                          'width' => '244',
                          'height' => '163',
                          'id' => 'image1',
                          'default' => ipThemeUrl('assets/img/ani.png'), 
                          'class' => 'img-responsive');
                           echo ipSlot('image', $options); 
                        ?>

Answer (score 0):

I dug into code. Unfortunately, alt tag is not implemented in the core at the moment.

If you really need this, you can check other slots how they implement attributes and do the same for this slot. Then create a pull request on GitHub and it will be added to the core with next release.